# KeyPress letters and spacing

Tags: vb.net

below is my code which is used for validating my text box. Currently i have it working for Letters only however i don't know how to allow spacing as well.

```
Private Sub txtFirstname_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtFirstname.KeyPress
    If Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
        MessageBox.Show("Letters only.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        ' Stop invalid character appearing in field
        e.KeyChar = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method `Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar)`

I would also recommend using `AndAlso` instead of `And` operator.

```
If Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) = False AndAlso Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
```

The operator `AndAlso` avoids redundant checks and will exit if the first condition is negative.

**EDIT**

Should look something like when you implement the function efficiently. You should also put this in a private subroutine and call that inside your KeyPress handler subroutine. So as to reuse the code in every event where you want to validate the input

```
Private Sub txtFirstname_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As     System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtFirstname.KeyPress
    ValidateInput(e)
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateInput(e As EventArgs)
If Char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar) = False Then        
    If Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) = False And Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) = False Then
                MessageBox.Show("Letters only.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                ' Stop invalid character appearing in field
                e.KeyChar = Nothing
        End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It still wont let me do any spacing in my textbox

Comment: What you can do is check for whiteSpaces outside the check for letters as If(whiteSpace) { If(isLetter)...} So the program will only check for letters only if there are no whitespaces

Answer (score 0):

You can check: Letters, Numbers and white spaces (Tab, space and enter) with this :

```
Private Sub textBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs)
  e.Handled = True
  Dim IsLetter As Boolean = (e.KeyChar >= 65 AndAlso e.KeyChar <= 90) OrElse (e.KeyChar >= 97 AndAlso e.KeyChar <= 122)
  Dim IsNumber As Boolean = (e.KeyChar >= 48 AndAlso e.KeyChar <= 57)
  Dim IsWhiteSpace As Boolean = (e.KeyChar = 9) OrElse (e.KeyChar = 13) OrElse (e.KeyChar = 32)
  If IsLetter OrElse IsWhiteSpace OrElse IsNumber Then
    e.Handled = False
    MessageBox.Show("Just numbers and letters and whitespaces")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you can check ASCII table for more customization